# Getting "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly informed" in Laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to get an ID from another table using foreignId but it won't let me.

My Users table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('user_id');
            $table->string('first_name', 40);
            $table->string('last_name', 40);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->foreignId('tier_id')->references('tier_id')->on('tiers');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My Tiers table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tiers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('tier_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->string('max_resolution');
            $table->integer('max_users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong, please help!

Solved, here's how:
Espresso's comment seems to help, migrations went through perfectly and all I needed to do is change the file name. Thank you!

Comment: Just change the name of your `tires` migration file, `2014_10_11_000000_create_tiers_table.php`, then the problem will be fixed

Comment: Espresso's comment helped, I tried others and they didn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm new to SOF, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cause** : You are getting this error, because your `users` migration run before the `tires` migration, and on that time the foreign key `tier_id` is not available from parent table `tires`

**Fix** : Just change the name of your `tires` migration file, `2014_10_11_000000_create_tiers_table.php`, this will fix your problem. Because now `tires` will run before `users` table

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your migrations like that
Parent table.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tiers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('tier_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->float('price');
            $table->string('max_resolution');
            $table->integer('max_users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Child table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('users_id');
            $table->string('first_name', 40);
            $table->string('last_name', 40);
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('tier_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            
            $table->foreign('tier_id')->references('tier_id')->on('tiers');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally produced when there's a mismatch between column types.

Your migration doesn't look wrong. Assuming that you get the error during migration, and your `tiers` migration comes before `users` migration, give this a try.

```
$table->foreignId('tier_id')->constrained('tiers', 'tier_id');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId

If the users migration file comes before tiers migration, then instead of creating the foreign key in the `users` migration file, add another migration to add the foreign key constraints after the `tiers` migration file. Something like this:

Your `users` migration file:

```
 ...
  $table->foreignId('tier_id');
 ...
```

New migration file `add_tier_id_foreign_key_to_users_table`

```
 //up
 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('tier_id')->references('tier_id')->on('tiers');
 });

 //down
 Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('users_tier_id_foreign');
 });
```